# evaluate a function in the calling environment

Tags: r

I have the function below.

```
test_fun <- function() {
  a <- 1
  b <- 2
}
```

Is there a way I run this function and a and b will be assigned in the parent environment (in this case globalenv)? I don't want to modify the function (no `assign` with envir or `<<-`), but call it in a way that what I want will be achieved.

Comment: If you don't want to modify the function, then you are out of luck. R environments just don't work that way. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? There may be a better way. Do you really need a function? Could you just use an expression instead? `code <- quote({a<-1; b<-2})` and then `eval(code)` when you want to execute it?

Comment: I had the whole script written, where the variables were variables in the globalenv and now I have to write a shiny app where I have to turn my entire script into a function to call it in shiny app... It seems I will have to rewrite it...

Comment: Well, R was designed as a functional language. The basic idea that functions should not have side effects like creating variables outside their scope is pretty fundamental. Even more so with Shiny. It's unclear to me what code would have worked in base R but not in shiny, but without a specific example it's hard to say what's going on. The shiny server function should act a lot like the global environment.

Answer (score 3):

Normally R functions return their outputs.  Functions such as `test_fun` 
are discouraged but if you want to do it anyways use `trace` as shown below.  This will cause the code given in the exit argument to run at function exit.  No packages are used.

```
trace("test_fun", exit = quote(list2env(mget(ls()), globalenv())), print = FALSE)
test_fun()
a;b
## [1] 1
## [1] 2
```

### Alternatives

Some alternatives for the exit= argument are the following.

(a) below is similar to above except that rather than leaving the objects loose in the global environment it first creates an environment `env` in the global environment and puts them there.

In (b) below, the objects are copied to `environment(test_fun)` which is the environment in which `test_fun` is *defined*.  (If `test_fun` is defined in the global environment then it gives the same result as the code at the top of the answer.)

In (c) below, the parent frame of `test_fun` is the environment of the caller of `test_fun` and can vary from one call to another if called from different places.  (If called from the global environment then it gives the same result as the code at the top of the answer.)

It would also be possible to add the current frame within test_fun to the search path using `attach` but there are a number of gotchas associated with that so it is not shown.

```
# (a) copy objects to environment env located in global environment
assign("env", new.env(), globalenv())
trace("test_fun", exit = quote(list2env(mget(ls()), env)), print = FALSE)

# (b) copy objects to environment in which test_fun is defined
trace("test_fun", 
  exit = quote(list2env(mget(ls()), environment(test_fun)), print = FALSE)

# (c) copy object to parent.frame of test_fun; 5 needed as trace adds layers
trace("test_fun", exit = quote(list2env(mget(ls()), parent.frame(5))),
  print = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

A better pattern to use, from the point of encapsulation, might be to have your custom function return a 2D vector containing the `a` and `b` values:

```
test_fun <- function() {
    a <- 1
    b <- 2
    return(c(a, b))
}

result <- test_fun()
a <- result[1]
b <- result[2]
```

The preferred method for passing information/work done in a function is via the return value, rather than trying to manage the issue of different scopes.